# Dreamspark Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: visual-studio, msdn

Will we see a release of VS2012 RC on [Dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/Default.aspx) (Student version of MSDN)?

Currently Dreamspark only has the beta. Is this the type of thing you need to make a request of Microsoft for?

Comment: The question should read: will we see a RTM Version of VS2012 Ultimate on MSDNAA/Dreamspark. VS 2012 Pro is currently available but it lacks IntelliTrace and uml diagrams/visio support. I'd also miss code coverage, although there should be other free tools around (ncrunch?).

Comment: as of today, VS2010 Professional and Premium are available on Dreamspark Premium, Ultimate is still RC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update this thread if anyone else is reading it, Dreamspark has updated to the RC.

*update 28 aug 2012*: the Release version is now available on dreamSpark

Comment: Exactly. I see no point in switching from RC to dreamspark version.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled the dreamspark copy and installed the 2012 RC edition from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#professional) .

There seems to be no adverse effects to doing this. It does have a timeout/time bomb on it but i'm hopeful it'll become available on dreamspark before then.

Comment: You didn’t need to uninstall the 11 beta though, you can just install the RC and it will upgrade the old one. Same with the RTM version, you won’t need to uninstall RC later.

Comment: When it's the timeout for 2012 RC?

Comment: 165 days from now.  (January 14th 2013)

Answer (score 0):

> Will we see a release of VS2012 RC on Dreamspark (Student version of MSDN)?

Ask Microsoft. It is extremely likely, you know.

> Is this the type of thing you need to make a request of Microsoft for?

No. DreamSpark only has released software, and it includes the development tools. As such, it would be natural for 2012 to be there - after all, 2012 will reture the old development tools - but NOT NOW.

You are the guy walking into a pizza store and complaining he is hungry because he has not yet eaten. You should at least wait until 2012 is released - and available for fully paying people - before thinking it should appear on DreaeamSpark. Why should MS maintain two different versions - which both per poliy would have timebombs and both of which are free? Makes no sense. Once it is released, 99% chance it will go to DreamSpark.

Comment: “Why should MS maintain two different versions” – Because they already do. Dreamspark does offer the 2012 *beta* which is replaced by the RC.